# How to add a "Referred to on pages ... " in the bibliography entries

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, natbib

I want to have a notice and hyperlink automatically added in each of my bibliography entries that says something like "Referred to on page (p1), (p2),..." with (p1) , (p2) clickable links to the corresponding page of my document where the corresponding reference is made.
Is this a setting available in one of the bibliography packages?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide more information about how you create the bibliography. The reason I ask is that you've set the tags `biblatex` and `natbib`, which are mutually incompatible.

Comment: Hey Mico, Im using bibtex but i didnt specify because i was interested in seeing solutions with the different bibliography packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `hyperref` package with the `pagebackref` option set. Then you need `renewcommand{\backref}[1]{Referred to on page #1}`.

#### MWE

backref.tex

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[pagebackref]{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\backref}[1]{Referred to on page #1}

\begin{document}

    A citation: \cite{whitaker:20:mwf}.

    \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
    \bibliography{backref}

\end{document}
```

backref.bib (excuse the shameless promoting of my paper)

```
@ARTICLE{whitaker:20:mwf,
    author = {S. T. Whitaker and G. Nataraj and J-F. Nielsen and J. A. Fessler},
    title = {Myelin water fraction estimation using small-tip fast recovery {MRI}},
    journal = {{Mag. Res. Med.}},
    volume = 84,
    number = 4,
    pages = {{1977--90}},
    month = oct,
    doi = {10.1002/mrm.28259},
    year = 2020
}
```